# How to use CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS?

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, cppcheck

I've been trying to use `clang-modernize` with `CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS` as recommended in the help of this tool.

With this option cmake generates a JSON file containing compile info like include paths ([see also](https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete/pull/148)).

This variable is accepted on the command line of cmake, 
but `cmake --help-variable CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS` doesn't work (which is coherent with [this mailing list posting](http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/cmake-developers/2012-June/004374.html)).

Has someone any idea on how to use it?

I could also use it with cppcheck.

**Some more info**

I've discovered on a [clang developer forum](http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/compile-commands-json-for-Windows-MSVC-td4033848.html) that this cmake feature is not available on all generators. This might change in the future, in the mean time my question remains and I will try too see what happen if I use other generators than Visual Studio.

Answer (score 91):

I suggest setting

```
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
```

in the CMakeList.txt

Comment: late to the show but for those also googling this, that would never have worked - it has to be set prior to the invocation of cmake. A 2nd cmake invocation would see it work however.

Comment: @HörmannHH Thanks for mentioning this. I had exactly this issue where compile_commands.json was never generated the first time, but only after the second configure.

Comment: Continuing my search I found this issue https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16588. I was able to make it happen in CMakeLists.txt if I put it right after my `project()` specification.

Comment: In the (now closed) issue linked by @Marnix, there was another cause for this issue that came from CMake overwriting the variable, even if `project()` was called before the variable was set. This was resolved for [CMake 3.18+](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/commit/fe19df49); for older versions, a workaround can be implemented by modifying the `set()` command to `set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON CACHE INTERNAL "")`.

Answer (score 38):

As of CMake 3.5 the `CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS` option is [supported by the Ninja and Makefiles generators](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/variable/CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.html).

That means to generate a JSON compile database one has to select a generator that supports it.

For example on UNIX just:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=1 /path/to/src
```

(as it uses the makefile generator there, by default)

Otherwise you can explicitly specify a generator like this:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=1 /path/to/src -G Ninja
```

Or:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=1 /path/to/src -G 'Unix Makefiles'
```

Or another makefiles variant that your cmake supports - a list of supported generators is included in the output of `cmake --help`.

Note that the compile database JSON file is generated at cmake execution time - not at compile time. Also, with recent clang versions (e.g. clang `>= 3.8`), `clang-modernize` was merged into `clang-tidy`.

Answer (score 5):

I too was not able to get to work on the Visual Studio generator.
It did, however, work using the "NMake Makefiles" generator.

```
C:\work\build>cmake -G "NMake Makefiles"  -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON  ..
```

Comment: Yep. As of Cmake 3.15.5: ["This option is implemented only by Makefile Generators and the Ninja. It is ignored on other generators."](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/variable/CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.html)

Answer (score 2):

The first one you use **CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON** in your CMakelists.txt
Or run CMake with following parameters:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=1 ..
```

1.Option:

Here is a simple source and build tree to make it clear.

```
.
├── build
├── cars
│   ├── car.cpp
│   ├── car.h
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── main.cpp
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "car.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "car - main function" << std::endl;
    showCarName();
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(Cars
    VERSION 0.1
    HOMEPAGE_URL "github/alitokur"
    LANGUAGES CXX
    )

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

    add_executable(carApp main.cpp)
    add_subdirectory(cars)
    target_link_libraries(carApp PRIVATE cars)
```

cars/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(cars OBJECT
    car.cpp
    )
target_include_directories(cars PUBLIC .)
```

And that's all, target link directories allow **main.cpp** to include the cars.h file without providing a relative path. You should use **set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)** after the **project()** definition because sometimes other tools override this setting and that's why you can't see compile_commands.json.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate explanation.

Answer (score 1):

#### CMake 3.17

As of CMake 3.17 you can now set `CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS` as an environment variable.

> The default value for CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS when there is no explicit configuration given on the first run while creating a new build tree. On later runs in an existing build tree the value persists in the cache as CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.

This is the best approach since you don't have to pollute project code or remember to set it individually for each project.

```bash
# Set this in your .bashrc or whatever environment you choose to set env variables
export CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=1
```

#### CMake 3.5

The second best approach is to pass `CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS` as a cache variable when configuring the project.

```
cmake -S . -B build -D CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=1
```

I prefer the new CMake 3.17 approach, since the 3.5 approach is easy to forget.

Comment: should compile_command.json be re-generated on incremental builds or is it an initial build thing?

Comment: It will be updated as needed. If you change a compiler option or file name. Then `compile_commands.json` will be updated by CMake.